# A good line-graph generator for my benchmarking?

Tags: php, c, graph, benchmarking, generator

To learn more about a language I rewrite some of the core functions, or compare basic speeds of each set of functions per problem to see what is more suited in real world situations.

Other than an ugly online line-graph generator which often only allows one or two series, I cannot find anything that would suit what I need.

Do you know of any online service, or better a easy to use framework/graph software I could feed data in for my benchmark results? It can be more complex (I might look into graphvis if it is suitable), but other benchmarks on for example OS's have clean formats, using a script I just cannot find that renders it.

Comment: Graphviz is not what you are looking for. It's focused on plotting relationships between different entities, not for diagram and benchmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomment you to use [PChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net), there is [example](http://dbench.googlecode.com/files/dbench_chart.png) of graph output.

Comment: Rats, this was the best one I had found before I asked, but the default chart sizes were a little too big for my taste. You made me realize that does not matter for my project, so I shall try it again :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?

Comment: A little too basic looking for me

Answer (score 0):

I found some implementations of using gnuplot as plugin to CMS. For example [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3agnuplot) and MediaWiki have this.